# What is the real difference between primitives and wrapper classes in Java

Tags: java, integer, int, wrapper, primitive

I understand stuff like:

1. Wrapper class creates an object and primitive does not create object
2. Wrapper classes are used with Collections to represent type
3. Wrappers have methods and can hold memory address/null and primitives hold default values
4. Primitives are fast compare to wrapper classes as there is no overhead of methods or object
5. How auto boxing and unboxing works
6. Wrapper class wraps primitive type

However, not able to understand the real difference between primitives and wrapper classes. Why there was a need to create two different ways to hold the data? Why we did not reuse what was already available?
For example, if wrapper classes were introduced before primitives then why we did not use wrapper classes instead of developing altogether a different way for similar purpose and vice versa.

Comment: Neither was "discovered". Wrapper classes exist *because primitives aren't objects*, and sometimes you need objects that hold `int`s and `double`s.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-Word discovered here is to emphasise on why part. Why someone had to create something new? And as I already mentioned, I understand that sometimes we need objects that hold primitives but why we did not make those new things compatible to work with what was already available?

Comment: Because _primitives are not objects_. It's like asking why we can't just make ice hot or the sun dark.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The real difference is that *primitive types* are not *reference types*.

In Java type system, reference types have a common root, while primitive types do not: All reference types are subtypes of `Object`. In comparison, primitive types do not have a common root; each primitive type is its own special unicorn.

This means that a variable declared with `Object` type can hold a value of any reference type, but it cannot hold a value of any primitive type.

This is a problem if you want to create data structures that are generally useful. Consider how you would implement a "dynamic array" data structure like ArrayList or Vector. You could use an array `Object[]` to store the elements, and that would work for all reference types. But since primitive types don't have a common root you would have to create a separate implementation for each primitive type.

To solve this problem, wrapper classes were created. Now, instead of needing 8 separate implementations of dynamic array (1 for reference types and 7 for primitive types), you could wrap each primitive value in an object, and just use the implementation for reference types.

Primitive types and wrapper classes were created at the same time, when the first design and implementation of Java 1.0 were made. The designers did not "reuse what was already available" because nothing was available: they built everything from scratch.

Could the designers have solved the problem some other way, maybe by creating a type system that had a common root for both primitive and reference types?  Yes, but they didn't, and they probably had good reasons: implementation complexity, ease of understanding, time to market, ...

Comment: This is really helpful, can you give me some idea about how exactly primitive is fast compare to wrapper? Is it because there is additional hope of reference with wrapper types or something more to it?

Comment: primitive  in method stack memory and wrapper is in JVM heap memory so primitive is fast compare to a wrapper

Comment: Yes following the object reference to read the wrapped primitive value may incur a cache miss, which takes time. There's also the memory bandwidth issue: wrapper objects are bigger than the values they wrap. With today's optimizing compilers that use techniques like scalar replacement (https://shipilev.net/jvm/anatomy-quarks/18-scalar-replacement/) the difference between wrapper and primitive is becoming less of an issue.

Comment: Shouldn't it be _"9 separate implementations of dynamic array (1 for reference types and 8 for primitive types)"_?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this question is pretty insightful. The answers are good and correct, but the underlying question that I think is worth asking is: should primitive types exist at all? We had a lot of discussion about this at the time and I think the reason things ended up the way they did had to do with the fact that Oak (later Java) was designed as an embedded language for the IOT (internet of things). If it had been originally designed as a server language, it might have been very different. I think primitive types are a legacy idea that is actually very harmful for exactly the reasons that Joni mentions. It's possible and desirable to have everything in the system extend Object.

How could you eliminate primitives? With a smarter JVM. HotSpot could turn special primitive objects into appropriate machine code wherever possible and there wouldn't be a need for autoboxing, wrappers or difficulties with the type system being split. The only limitation that I think would need to be placed on Integer, Float, Double, etc., is that they would have to be final. This would allow these classes to be optimized anywhere possible as if they were primitives without actually having primitives in the language. You could even have syntactic abbreviations like 'int', 'float' and 'double' for these special classes, but the important thing is that the type system would be better if it was fully unified.

But you don't start trying to build such a thing when you're thinking about smart toasters. What happened to Java in terms of its wild success was a pure accident. It happened to be a solution to a lot of web-related issues just sitting there at the right time. But it wasn't planned that way, so there are a lot of things people would like to have back. I think a lot of people at Sun/Oracle would eliminate primitives in hindsight.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.Can you emphasise more on how primitives are more useful for embedded systems or otherwise as both(primitives and wrappers) were designed at the same time from scratch?

Comment: @Hardik The main issue in embedded systems is often CPU and RAM limitations. You can't have a big complicated VM in a toaster because it's not going to have a 2GHz processor and 16GB of RAM. 

The creators of Java didn't come up with either of these ideas. They came from much earlier systems. Primitive types have arguably been around from the dawn of computers. Objects have been around since the roots of SmallTalk took hold in the late 60's. Honestly, people think that corporations innovate when they mostly repackage ideas for the market. Academia innovates.